# Entity Framework or where rather than and where clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` where the `Tuple` `Items` represent the lower and upper values (respectively) for use when querying for `Users` that have received `Strikes`.

For example:

```
var ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(0, 5),
    new Tuple<int, int>(9, 28)
};
```

Using the above ranges, I want to query my `User` entities for `Users` that have a `Strike` property value that falls between these lower and upper bounds taking each `List` element into consideration.

Using a `foreach` loop with a `where` clause to build a query, the `where` is applied using `and` whereas I am looking to utilise `or`:

```
var usersQueryable = _dbContext.Users.AsQueryable();

foreach (var range in ranges)
{
    usersQueryable = usersQueryable.Where(u => u.strikes >= range.Item1 
                                               && u.strikes < range.Item2);
}
```

I tried using `Concat` and `Union` however this results in some projection errors. Is `Concat` or `Union` the correct way to go about this, or is there another solution?

Comment: Maybe `_dbContext.Users.AsQueryable().Where(u => ranges.Any(r => u.strikes >= r.Item1 && u.strikes < r.Item2);` not sure if EF can translate that

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want `Users` with a `Strike` between your values, or with a `Strike` higher than `range.Item1` OR lower than `range.Item2` ? anyway, you will probably have a problem using a `foreach`, as the values are passed by reference.

Comment: @Charlieface , it is quite elegant, I am thinking the same, but not sure if EF can translate that.